# Instantiation of signed chaincode packages in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to apply the packaging method for the chaincode which enables me to enforce signatures from multiple organizations and make sure that chaincode cannot be effectively instantiated if signatures from relevant participants in the channel are not collected.

a) From Org1 context:

```
# peer chaincode package -n mycc -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/ -v 1 -s -S -i "AND('Org1.admin','Org2.admin')" ccpack.out
2018-12-03 22:49:46.032 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2018-12-03 22:49:46.032 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc

root@bdc554f0a918:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode signpackage ccpack.out signedccpack.out
Wrote signed package to signedccpack.out successfully

root@bdc554f0a918:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode install signedccpack.out
2018-12-03 22:50:21.125 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> INFO 001 Installed remotely response:<status:200 payload:"OK" >
```

b) From Org2 context:

```
root@bdc554f0a918:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode signpackage ccpack.out signedccpack.out
Wrote signed package to signedccpack.out successfully

root@bdc554f0a918:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode install signedccpack.out
2018-12-03 22:50:32.414 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> INFO 001 Installed remotely response:<status:200 payload:"OK" >
```

c) From either Org context:

```
root@bdc554f0a918:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C channel1 -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
2018-12-03 22:50:42.946 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2018-12-03 22:50:42.950 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg cannot get package for chaincode (mycc:1.0)
```

d) The chaincode is present on Org1 Peer 1:

```
root@af99b3698322:/var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes# ls
mycc.1
```

e) The chaincode is present on Org2 Peer 1:

```
root@2fd1355259a8:/var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes# ls
mycc.1
```

Any recommendations as to the process or the cli syntax structure would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you created the package as version 4 ( `-v 4` ) and are trying to upgrade as version 4.0 (`-v 4.0`)

Comment: I updated a description of my issue above to show that an attempt to solve it with an installation from scratch does not work.

Comment: I found the problem: the package was created as v1 but instantiation used v1.0. This meant that the package was considered missing.